# Under my constructor for an array, I have a toString method that prints out the contents. But it's telling me it isn't resolved to a variable

Tags: java, arrays

So my constructor creates an array, and I want my toString method to display the contents. However, I'm getting an error telling me that table[i] can not be resolved to a variable, even though it was created in the constructor. Please help!

```
public int size = 38;
public int first = 0;
public int last = 2;
public int count = 1;


public Table()
{
    int[] table = new int[size]; 
    table[0] = first;
    table [size-1] = last;
    for(int i = 1; i < size-1; i++){
        if(count == first | count == last)
            count++;
        table[i] = count;
        count++;
        }
}

public String toString(){
    String string = "Wheel: 0";
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        string = string + "-" + table[i] ; //table[i] CAN NOT BE RESOLVED TO A VARIABLE
    return string;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `table` is defined locally in your constructor.

```
int[] table = new int[size];
```

You have to declare it outside the constructor:

```
int[] table;
public Table()
{
    table = new int[size]; 
...
```

Comment: That's giving me a null pointer exception :( My driver looks like this;

          public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  Table t = new Table();
  System.out.println(t.toString());

 }

Comment: @KevinYasmine Please add the code and the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @KevinYasmine the if condition wont be true in all cases, so all values of array wont be initialized, which will give null pointer exception.You need to add else part & initialize table[i] with some value.

Comment: @Sumedh Uhmm when count reaches 2, it will be true, and in that case 2 won't be added to the array, but it will be increased to 3 before it gets added.